# Android PdfDocument.writeTo causing ANR for large documents

Tags: android

I am creating PdfDocument using native Android library PrintedPdfDocument. The code below works fine when total pages count approximately under 15. However for larger document, [PdfDocument.writeTo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html) call is causing ANR and system kills my app. I am executing the code in AsyncTask. This is particularly a problem on Android L(Samsung Note PRO); Android M can handle up to 40 pages reliably (tested).

```
// open a new document
document = new PrintedPdfDocument(_activity, printAttributes);
// crate a page description
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(pageWidth, pageHeight, pageIndex).create();
page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
content.draw(page.getCanvas());
// finish the page
document.finishPage(page);

try
{
       File pdfPath = new File(FILE_PATH);
       // This statement causing ANR
       document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(pdfPath));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // log
}
// close the document
document.close();
```

What should I do with this code to create large PDF documents on Android L? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to use mupdf that may help you

Comment: @parikdhakan Thanks for the suggestion. MuPDF is not free - it is licensed under AGPL.

Comment: @Roy Did you ever find a solution to this problem?